# Using set() in ArrayList doesn't get it updated

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this member function from a class MathMatrix, that extends ArrayList< ArrayList < Double > >.

```
public void LUFactPivoting(MathMatrix l, MathMatrix u) throws LUException, CloneNotSupportedException {
    double [] Parray = {1,2,3,4};
    P = new MathVector(Parray);
    MathMatrix temp = new MathMatrix(this);
    int n = ncols;
    double mult;

    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        System.out.println("TEMP: " + u.toString());
        this.partialPivotingStep(l, temp, k);
        for (int i = k + 1; i < n; i++) {
            if(temp.getElem(k, k) == 0) System.out.println("ZERO");
            mult = temp.getElem(i, k) / temp.getElem(k, k);
            l.setElem(i, k, mult);
            for (int j = k; j < n; j++) {
                double newval = temp.getElem(i, j) - mult * temp.getElem(k, j);
                temp.setElem(i, j, newval);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        l.setElem(i, i, 1.0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
            u.setElem(i, j, temp.getElem(i, j));
        }
    }
}
```

I am using `ArrayList.set()` but the object doesn't get updated when I call `this.partialPivotingStep(l, temp, k)`, so the object temp stays the same as initialized when I pass it as an argument (but changes when I use it in `LUFactPivoting` scope). What's the problem?

Comment: What do `partialPivotingStep` and `new MathMatrix(this)` do?

Comment: partialPivoting checks the maximum value from temp(k,colnum) to temp(n,colnum), and swaps that row using Collections.swap(), on temp and l

Comment: I found the error. I didn't notice I was calling this.set() instead of calling it to the argument. That's what you getting when you are tired while coding! Thank you